# "built-in method sum" weird message when printing a sum

Tags: python, numpy

Using Python NumPy to calculate the sum of the column of a matrix:

```
import numpy
from StringIO import StringIO

fileName = 'test2.csv'
myFile = open(fileName,'r')
print "Reading data from '%s' ..." % fileName
data = myFile.read() 
myFile.close()

data = numpy.genfromtxt(StringIO(data), delimiter=',', usecols=(0,1,2))
print "Calculating ..."

print data[:,2]
sumA1 = data[:,2].sum
print "shape =", data.shape
print "sumA1 =", str(sumA1)
print "ok"
```

Then contents of `test2.csv`:

```
12,13,14,17
1,2,3,4
12,13,14,17
1,2,3,4
12,13,14,17
1,2,3,4
12,13,14,17
1,2,3,4
12,13,14,17
```

I get this output

```
Reading data from 'test2.csv' ...
Calculating ...
[ 14.   3.  14.   3.  14.   3.  14.   3.  14.]
shape = (9, 3)
sumA1 = <built-in method sum of numpy.ndarray object at 0x00FD8EF8>
ok
```

Why can't I get "sumA1 = 82" insted of that weird message? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to make a call of the `sum` function. Just replace this piece of code:

```
sumA1 = data[:,2].sum
```

with this one:

```
sumA1 = data[:,2].sum()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works as well with:

sumA1 = numpy.sum(data[:,2])